# ADAL vs MSAL for .netcore api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am in the process of creating a .netcore API which calls Graph API, to get the user groups.

I was reading through the microsoft documentation , which showed I could use ADAL or MSAL.

I am not sure which one to use.

My API is used by a third party app, so I guess that will not have the same Application ID.
So is ADAL the best option for me?
I am really new to Azure AD can any one suggest a way to access the Access tocken with ADAL and without user login?

Answer (score 4):

ADAL.NET is used with Azure AD v1.0 and MSAL.NET is used with Azure AD v2.0 .

MSAL(v2.0 endpoint) allows you to acquire tokens for users signing-in to your application with Azure AD (work and school accounts), Microsoft (personal) accounts (MSA) or Azure AD B2C. It will also soon support a direct connection to ADFS 2019 . ADAL(V1.0 endpoint)  supports Azure AD (work and school accounts), but not personal accounts , and supports a direct connection to ADFS 2016 or ADFS v2 .

You can refer to below articles for more details :

[Comparing the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint with the v1.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison)

[Differences between ADAL.NET and MSAL.NET applications](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal)

Comment: To add to this, MSAL .NET will soon support brokered authentication (using Authenticator App on iOS or Authenticator App or Intune Company Portal on Android) to have full feature parity with ADAL .NET.